# c++ outside of a class, is the order of varaible declaration garanteed to be the order of construction?

Tags: c++, initialization

Lets say I have the code:

main.cpp:

```
my_obj1 obj1("hello obj1");
my_obj2 obj2("hello obj2");

int main()
{
    :
    :
}
```

I want to know if `obj1` is always garanteed to be created before `obj2`.

If these two objects where in a class I think we can say that would be true.

Comment: "especially if you use the constructor list to create the objects" - that is not true, order of initialization is determined by order of declaration in object, not by order in constructor initialization list.

Comment: @sklott Ah, ok that's useful actually and explains why we get warnings when you have a constructor list that is "out of order", thanks : )

Comment: @sklott also I removed that part incase it mis-leads anyone reading it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, **within a single translation unit**, [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Dynamic_initialization) of global variables is guaranteed to be sequenced in the order of their definitions. That means `obj1` is guaranteed to be initialized before `obj2`, and destroyed after `obj2`.

> 3) *Ordered dynamic initialization*, which applies to all other non-local variables: within a single translation unit, initialization of these variables is always [sequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) in exact order their definitions appear in the source code.

BTW: The [initialization order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order) of class members are also determined by their declaration order, which has nothing to do with how you specify them in member initializer list.

> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.

Comment: oh great thanks : ) ... just waiting for the 6 minutes to mark it up :o